# Pop-up Loop: Stop Duplication/Triplication/X When Adding Data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Can anyone help me to track the line of code/s which causes the duplication/triplication/x when adding a data in a pop-up form? New/Update/Delete functions are fine except for Add.

The scenario is when I'm adding a data, it should be saved once (which was perfectly working before) but it's now saving twice or trice (so we now have 2 identical copies of data for example).. and when I'm adding another data, it's now saving x2 or x3 of the number of data that was saved before (so we now have another 4 identical copies of data).. the hell! It supposes to save 2 unique data only right? But we have now 2 + 4 identical copies of data. Please help..

Here's the **html file**:

```
<div id="man_contact_person">
<form id="form_client_contact" action="" method="post">
    <span id="client_d_result"></span>
    <table class="children_table">
        <th>
            <tr style="font-weight:bold">
                <td style="width: 10px"></td>
                <td>Person</td>
                <td>Position</td>
                <td>Contact No</td>
                <td>Archive?</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="hidden" id="client_d_id" name="client_d_id" /><input type="hidden" id="client_h_id" name="client_h_id" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="person" name="person" placeholder="Full Name" style="width:200px;"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="position" name="position" placeholder="Position" style="width:200px;"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="contact_no" name="contact_no" placeholder="mobile/landline/wireless" style="width:200px;"></td>
                <td align="center"><?php input_checkbox('is_archive', ''); ?></td>
                <td align="center">
                    <input type="button" class="small_save" id="btn_add_client_d" name="btn_add_client_d" />
                    <input type="button" class="small_save" id="btn_save_client_d" name="btn_save_client_d" />
                    <input type="button" class="small_new" id="btn_new_client_d" name="btn_new_client_d" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </th>
        <tbody id="client_children">
    </table>
</form>
```

Here's the **js file**:

```
//some codes...

$(document).ready(function(){
    //some codes...

    $("#man_contact_person").dialog({ //the popup form
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 810,
        height: 500,
        modal: true,
        title: "Manage Contact Persons"
    });

    $("#btn_contact_person").click(function(){ //when calling popup form
         if ($("#message").is(":visible")){
            $("#man_contact_person").dialog( "open" );
            get_client_children($("#id").val());
        } else{
            if ($("#cname").val() != '' || $("#fname").val() != ''){
                $("#man_contact_person").dialog( "open" );
                get_client_children($("#id").val());
            } else{
                alert("Please save the client's data first.");
            }
        }
    });

    //some codes...
});

//some codes...

function reset_client_d(){ //resetting the fields
    $("#client_d_id").val('');
    $("#form_client_contact #person").val('');
    $("#form_client_contact #position").val('');
    $("#form_client_contact #contact_no").val('');
    $('#form_client_contact #is_is_archive').prop('checked', false);

    $("#btn_add_client_d").show();
    $("#btn_save_client_d").hide();
}

function client_d_add(client_h_id){ //adding data
    var params = 'client_h_id=' + client_h_id +
        '&person=' + $('#form_client_contact #person').val() +
        '&position=' + $('#form_client_contact #position').val() +
        '&contact_no=' + $('#form_client_contact #contact_no').val() + 
        '&is_archive=' + $('#form_client_contact #is_archive').val() + '';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'client_d_add.php',
        data: params,
        success: function(data){
            get_client_children(client_h_id);
            $("#client_d_result").show();
            reset_client_d();
        }
    });
}

function get_client_children(client_h_id){ //display for popup form
    var params = 'client_h_id=' + client_h_id;
    $("#form_client_contact #is_is_archive").click(function(){
        $("#form_client_contact #is_archive").val(($("#form_client_contact #is_is_archive").prop("checked") ? "Y" : "N"));
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'get_client_children.php',
        data: params,
        success: function(data){
            $('#client_children').html(data);

            $('#btn_save_client_d').hide();
            $('#btn_save_client_d').click(function(){client_d_update(client_h_id);});
            $('#btn_add_client_d').click(function(){client_d_add(client_h_id);});
            $('#btn_new_client_d').click(function(){reset_client_d();});

            $('.edit_client_d').click(function(){
                return client_d_select(this.id);
            });
        }
    });
}

//some codes...
```

Comment: drop some html in here

Comment: @madalinivascu html was now added.

Comment: What does the browser debugger show  in the network tab? Is there one one or maybe multiple POSTs going out to the server? Did you try debugging the server code that saves the data? Is it being called multiple times? Try scaling back the JavaScript and AJAX. I know it's the cool thing to do, but you are manually doing things that the browser and/or jQuery can/should do themselves. Try using a normal posted form without JavaScript.

Comment: @RoToRa There's a looping of function is happening. What I'm trying to do now is to refresh the pop-up form everytime it loads. Do you think it's the best solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found it: You are assigning the click handlers multiple times:

```
$('#btn_save_client_d').click(function(){client_d_update(client_h_id);});
```

Every time `get_client_children` is called you add a new click handler, so when the save button is clicked the save function is called multiple times.

Generally you should assign event handlers once on page initialization.

Instead of passing the id to the save function as a parameter, write it to a hidden field in the form and post to together with the other data.

And I'll repeat it: Scale back with the JavaScript and AJAX. Your code seems quite over-engined.

Comment: I figured that out already and tried to move that `$('#btn_save_client_d')` to somewhere and it works. But whenever I close the form now and open it again, duplication occurs again. I have (2) solutions to try now. And yes I'm scaling back, I always do this whenever I messed up my coding. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: Hey. It's all working now! I see no more problems. I just removed the button-click functions inside `get_client_children` and put them inside the `$(document).ready(.....);`. And my code is looking nice now after an hour of fixing it :)